# trying to understand this heap analysis to determine a memory leak or just massive amount of memory needed

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, stanford-nlp

I am parsing in an html file that is 3mb and using Stanfords pos tagger with it, always failing because of OOM. If I have 1gb in the heap, it gives a heap error. If I have 7gb of heap it gives GC error(spend too much time gc'ing so throw error). I have tried changing the GC to allow more time to gc, as well as changing the GC implementation. So what I have observed is that changing the heap size does not resolve the oom error.

I have a main class which uses Stanfords API(tokenizes string and tags the word) and passes in an entire html page(a massive amount of numbers). When I run a heap dump, it says that java.lang.Thread has 700mb of retained heap. Almost all of the memory is inside a double[][] but I don't know how else to make use of this information to determine a memory leak. I have been trying to find a good MAT tutorial(memory analyzer tool for eclipse) but having difficulties finding a good resource...

here is a stack trace

```
The thread java.lang.Thread @ 0xdb8acd90 main keeps local variables with total size 721,109,984 (86.33%) bytes.

The memory is accumulated in one instance of "double[][]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
The stacktrace of this Thread is available. See stacktrace.



Keywords
double[][]

Details »



*main
  at java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.<init>()V (OutOfMemoryError.java:48)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.stringTagsAt(I)[Ljava/lang/String; (TestSentence.java:732)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getApproximateScores(Ledu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/History;)[D (TestSentence.java:393)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.getScores(Ledu/stanford/nlp/tagger/maxent/History;)[D (TestSentence.java:370)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.scoresOf([II)[D (TestSentence.java:713)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(Ledu/stanford/nlp/sequences/SequenceModel;[[D)Ledu/stanford/nlp/util/Pair; (ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:91)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.sequences.ExactBestSequenceFinder.bestSequence(Ledu/stanford/nlp/sequences/SequenceModel;)[I (ExactBestSequenceFinder.java:31)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.runTagInference()V (TestSentence.java:322)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.testTagInference()Ljava/util/ArrayList; (TestSentence.java:312)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.TestSentence.tagSentence(Ljava/util/List;Z)Ljava/util/ArrayList; (TestSentence.java:135)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagSentence(Ljava/util/List;Z)Ljava/util/List; (MaxentTagger.java:998)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagCoreLabelsOrHasWords(Ljava/util/List;Ledu/stanford/nlp/process/Morphology;Z)Ljava/util/List; (MaxentTagger.java:1788)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger$TaggerWrapper.apply(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (MaxentTagger.java:1291)
  at edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger.tagString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (MaxentTagger.java:933)
  at PageTagger.tagText(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (PageTagger.java:76)
  at PageTagger.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V (PageTagger.java:40)*
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please let me know if I can provide any information.

Answer (score 2):

You need much more memory than you are allocating to process a 3GB web page in one chunk. My naive guess is on the order of a few dozen GB. My recommendation is to split the web page up into smaller parts, and run on each part separately? The part-of-speech tagger operates on a sentence-by-sentence level anyways, so if your document has coherent sentences this is a natural boundary to split on.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, 3mb. Thank you for the help, I got as far as getting the program to work, now I am still trying to understand more about the memory analyzing portion and why it happened.

Comment: Ah, that should be ok to run in 7GB. How are you calling CoreNLP? What does the webpage look like? It could be some funky property of the webpage itself (e.g., it's one long sentence).

Comment: basically they have a method called tagText and I pass in the entire html, which is literally just millions of numbers separated by white space "123 456 12312" and so forth, its lets say.... 10 numbers across and I have no idea how many new lines. I am sending in chunks of the html and it works, but as a whole it gets OOM.

Comment: OK, then this is likely just due to the sentence being too long for the tagger to handle as one chunk. I think sending it in chunks is the right answer. Also, out of curiosity, why are you tagging this document? If it really is just numbers, every tag should be `CD`?